# New tab/window links in Safari with a redirect of the current page

Tags: javascript

So I have this script here, it's main purpose is to open a specified link in a new tab/window and THEN redirect the current window (where the script has been fired, not the new tab).

It works as follow. You specify a link to listen on it for a click event, once it's clicked two instructions should fire up. New tab should be opened and the current window should be redirected.

The problem is that this script works in chrome, but in safari this script results just in a redirect to the specified url, the new tab/window does't not open up.

```
function openTab(url) {
    // Create link in memory
    var a = window.document.createElement("a");
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.href = url;

    // Dispatch fake click
    var e = window.document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(e);
}

var aNode = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
/* this is current link's url, just click copy link address you want to affect, and paste it here between ''*/
/* it supports multiple buttons with different links */
currentUrl = ['https://www.google.com/intl/en/ads/'],
/*this link loads in new tab */
newTabUrl = 'http://www.google.com/',
/* this link loads after the 'newTabUrl' is opened */
redirectUrl = 'http://www.youtube.com/';

        for (var t = 0; currentUrl["length"] > t; t++) {
            for (i in aNode) {
                if (aNode[i].href && aNode[i].href == currentUrl[t]) {
                    aNode[i].href = redirectUrl; // without this the page will be not      redirected in chrome (second instruction in the addEventListener, function below does not fire up somehow...)
                    aNode[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                    openTab(newTabUrl);       
                    window.location = redirectUrl;
                    console.log('fired');  //debugging
                    });
                  console.log('affected!'); //debugging
                } 
              console.log(i); //debugging
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question, but the behavior in question may be unsettling to the user if they don't expect it.

Comment: Unless you mention about the new tab under the button on your page.

Comment: That's true - then they'd expect it!

Comment: I have to mention that the openTab function works in Safari, but in the script above it somehow doesn't fire up. But the weird thing is that the next instruction (below the openTab(newTabUrl) does fire up.)